# UITableView with Multiple Columns

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

Is it possible to create  multiple columns in UITableView, as my requirement demand me to do this, If it is possible how i can i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can create custom class for UITableViewCell and use it in method cellForRowAtIndexPath OR you can create label or any and subview in cell.contentView.

Answer (score 2):

You may use UICollectionView for that. Or simply build each UITableViewCell with needed labels and elements in cycle with columns count

Answer (score 2):

**First thing** you need to do is take a look at `UITableViewCell` Documetation and Read the Content given there. If you read it properly, you'll get the Answer in the form of these **Steps :**

1. Create Custom `UITableViewCell` with `UILabel` equals to Number of Columns.
2. Use this `UITableViewCell` in your `UITableView`.
3. Fill each Row of `UITableView` with your Database Table Rows.

**Tutorials** to Integrate custom `UITableViewCell` :

1. [Creating custom UITableViewCell from XIBs – step by step tutorial](http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/)
2. [Crafting Custom UITableView Cells](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)

GoodLuck !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `CustomCell` there will be scrolling issue. So the best way to do this is `UICollectionView` for ios6. I did it with `CustomCell` also so if you are working for ios5 I will guide you.